# How to package deactivation of a Workflow?

Tags: managed-package, workflow

We publish a managed package in Salesforce which consists of triggers and workflows. In version say *x*, we added 4 workflows and in next version *x+1*, we wanted to deactivate those in managed package which whenever a customer upgrades should lead to deactivation of previously activated workflows from version *x* but it is not working as expected.

Seems like this issue is related to upgrade process because when *x+1* is directly installed in a new org, the workflows get marked as disabled but upgrades doesn't deactivate them. Is that a restriction by Salesforce?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my experience, workflow rules do not get de-activated on upgrade - I think it is one of those things where they don't want to override the customers decision to turn off a workflow rule, in the same way page layouts don't get updated by upgrades

The only way I know of is to include release notes explaining where to find the rules (e.g. create a view and filter by namespace x) and then tell them to deactivate them.

Comment: [Doc reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_attributes.htm) in support - under Workflow Rule, the Active attribute is subscriber-editable, so it won't be updated via push upgrades.

Comment: Thanks @BritishBoyinDC for your inputs. Appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed for the doc link.